# Get the key from a specific value in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary such as:

```
task_list
[['Genus', {'Genus1': ['Sp1_A'], 'Genus2': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B']}], ['Family', {'Family1': ['Sp1_A'], 'Family2': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B']}], ['SubFamily', {'SubFamily1': ['Sp1_A'], 'SubFamily1': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B']}], ['Order', {'Order': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B', 'Sp1_A']}]]
```

so here is the content:

```
>>> for i in task_list:
...     print(i)
... 
['Genus', {'Genus1': ['Sp1_A'], 'Genus2': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B']}]
['Family', {'Family1': ['Sp1_A'], 'Family2': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B']}]
['SubFamily', {'SubFamily1': ['Sp1_A'], 'SubFamily2': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B']}]
['Order', {'Order': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B', 'Sp1_A']}]
```

And I have a tree file where I can print :

```
>>> for leaf in tree:
...     print(leaf.name)
... 
YP_001.1
Sp2_A
YP_002.1
YP_003.1
Sp1_A
YP_004.1
YP_005.1
Sp2_B
Sp2_A
```

As you can see `Sp1_A Sp2_A` and `Sp1_B` (with Sp1_A present twice) are all in the values of the dic:

And I would like for each `leaf.name`, to add a `tag` with the following command : `leaf.add_features(tag=tag)` where `tag` should be the `GenusNumber` from the `task_list`

So here :

```
for leaf in tree:
    tag=the corresponding `key` of the `value` in the `dic`
    leaf.add_features(tag=tag)
    print(tag)
```

I should get:

```
Genus2 (corresponding to Sp2_A from task_list key)
Genus1 (corresponding to Sp1_A from task_list key)
Genus2 (corresponding to Sp2_B from task_list key)
Genus2 (corresponding to Sp2_A from task_list key)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: There's no `'Sp1_B'` anywhere in the dictionary.

Comment: @Austin I edited the post (some mistakes were present)

Comment: @JonathanGagne with nothing special, I do not add a tag for YP_* sequences

Comment: *"tag should be the FamilyNumber from the task_list"* or GenusNumber?

Comment: @Austin The Genus_Number you are right

Comment: @JonathanGagne SpNb_Letter should belong to only one category within Family, Genus, Subfamily etc.  Sp1_A belongs to Family1 and Genus1 for instance but here i am interested only about Genus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `'Genus'` dictionary checking for the value and retrieve the key:

```
for leaf in tree:
    tag = None
    for k, v in task_list[0][1].items():
        if leaf.name in v:
            tag = k
    if tag:
        leaf.add_features(tag=tag)
        print(tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your data structure is wrong.
As far as I understand, your array elements have a relationship which is can be pointed by dictionaries. Array elements should not have a relationship.

In you example, `task_list[0][0]` is the key of `task_list[0][1]`.
You can define it as as `dict`:

```
genus = {'Genus1': ['Sp1_A'], 'Genus2': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B']}
```

If you have more than one key like `genus`, you can also embed it in a `dict`:

```
task_list = {'Genus': {'Genus1': ['Sp1_A'], 'Genus2': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B']},
             'Family': {'Family1': ['Sp1_A'], 'Family2': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B']},
             ...}
```

If you do this, then it will be much more easy to program what you want:

```
for root_key, root_val in task_list.items():
    print(root_key) # Genus

    for child_key, child_val in root_val.items(): # '{'Genus1': ['Sp1_A'], 'Genus2': ['Sp2_A', 'Sp2_B']}'
        print(child_key, child_val) # Genus1, ['Sp1_A']
```